# Installed apache2 on Ubuntu 18.04, started it, it answers requests from localhost, but not from outside

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, apache2

I have set up a server under Ubuntu 18.04 from scratch with apache2. I configured apache2 and I was able to start it.

I can confirm it is running

```
prompt:~$ apachectl status
              Apache Server Status for localhost (via ::1)

Server Version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.0g
Server MPM: prefork
Server Built: 2018-10-10T18:59:25
  __________________________________________________________________

Current Time: Monday, 18-Mar-2019 18:42:58 CET
Restart Time: Monday, 18-Mar-2019 16:13:58 CET
Parent Server Config. Generation: 1
Parent Server MPM Generation: 0
Server uptime: 2 hours 28 minutes 59 seconds
Server load: 0.00 0.00 0.00
Total accesses: 3 - Total Traffic: 22 kB
CPU Usage: u0 s0 cu0 cs0
.000336 requests/sec - 2 B/second - 7.3 kB/request
1 requests currently being processed, 5 idle workers

____W_..........................................................
................................................................
......................

Scoreboard Key:
"_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
"W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
"C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
"I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process
```

and I can access it locally

```
 prompt:~$ wget localhost
 --2019-03-18 18:45:31--  http://localhost/
 Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
 Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:80... connected.
 HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
 Length: 10918 (11K) [text/html]
 Saving to: ‘index.html’

 index.html          100%[===================>]  10.66K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

 2019-03-18 18:45:31 (139 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [10918/10918]
```

but I cannot reach it from outside. Any connection from the outside just times out, it is not refused immediately, and it not failing because of "network unreachable". The attempted accesses from outside aren't logged in `/var/log/apache2/access.log` nor in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. What can be the cause for this behaviour and how can I fix it?

EDIT: More on the network: The server is placed in a university network and should be visible to web-wide public by firewall configuration. I tried to access it using `firefox` and `wget` with the same results. I tried both "near neighbours" and external computers.

EDIT2: Output from `nmap`:

```
 Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-18 19:16 CET
 Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
 Host is up (0.00021s latency).
 Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
 rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost.localdomain
 Not shown: 992 closed ports
 PORT     STATE SERVICE
 22/tcp   open  ssh
 25/tcp   open  smtp
 80/tcp   open  http
 443/tcp  open  https
 587/tcp  open  submission
 3306/tcp open  mysql
 7937/tcp open  nsrexecd
 7938/tcp open  lgtomapper
```

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.13 seconds

Comment: Hello, please provide more information... Where the server is located - in your LAN, or it is VPS, or...? How did you tried to access it from outside?

Comment: @pa4080 Question edited

Comment: Ok, if the server has a public IP, probably you must allow the incoming access in the server's port 80 (and 443 when HTTPS is enabled). I would suggest you to use `ufw` at this stage. So install it first: `sudo apt install ufw`. Then allow port 80, by one of the following commands: `sudo ufw allow 80/tcp` or `sudo ufw allow HTTP`, or `sudo ufw allow Apache`. Set the default policies `sudo ufw default deny incoming && sudo ufw default allow outgoing`. And finally do: `sudo ufw enable`.

Comment: According to the usage of `nmap 127.0.0.1` - it is false: https://askubuntu.com/q/906517/566421

Comment: @pa4080: Thanks a lot, ufw was the culprit. IN fact, it was active and blocking the connections.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help in the comments from @pa4080 I found the solution: `ufw` was active and blocking the connections on ports 80 and 443. I set `ufw` to inactive for the time being and the connections are working now.